# Trouble executing an event

Tags: javascript

**Updated External JS Sheet Code Below**
I am attempting to execute a simple photogallery.  The task for my class is to hover over a small image and have the alt text and image displayed in the larger box and when the mouse leaves the text the background image should display as they were originally
Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my (broken) external Javascript sheet:

```
function upDate(PreviewPic){
    var imageLarge= document.getElementById('image');
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = PreviewPic.alt;
    document.getElementById('image').backgroundImage =imageLarge.src;
}

function unDo(){
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
}
```

Comment: So what's happening (or not happening)? What errors do you get in the developer console? Note that there's no such function as `getElementByClass`. Did you mean `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: With the updated JS functions (see above) I am getting no errors in the console when i hover, but only the text change is activating, the image/background is not changing @j08691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one works vanilla js and i commented a lot of the stuff, you said you're doing it for a class if its a coding class hopefully this helps you learn.the code snipit works but is not styled in a good way so try it out in your editor with you're css.

```js
//grabing the ellements by id 
var imgOne = document.getElementById("img1");
var imgTwo = document.getElementById("img2");
var imgThree = document.getElementById("img3");
var displayText = document.getElementById("displayText");
var displayImg = document.getElementById("displayImg");


//add eventlisteners to events 
//this can be done in the html; but i prefer it in the javaScript
// event listeners for first img
imgOne.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    displayImg.src = imgOne.src;
    displayText.innerHTML = imgOne.alt;
});
// to replace 
imgOne.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    displayImg.src = "";
    displayText.innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
});

// event listeners for second img
// adds the stuff
imgTwo.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    displayImg.src = imgTwo.src;
    displayText.innerHTML = imgTwo.alt;
});
// reverts stuff
imgTwo.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    displayImg.src = "";
    displayText.innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
});

// event listener for third img
imgThree.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    displayImg.src = imgThree.src;
    displayText.innerHTML = imgThree.alt;
});
imgThree.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    displayImg.src = "";
    displayText.innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "image">
 <!--    you could create a text node and append it rather than adding a p tag
        but hard codeing it is a little easier  -->
    <img src="" alt="" id="displayImg">
   
    <p id="displayText">Hover over an image below to display here.</p>
    </div>

    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" id="img1">

    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" id="img2">

    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" id="img3">
<!--    i moved the script to the bottom so that you're html will load before the js
        this can prevent some "can not get/append/set ****** to undefined" errors.
        (i've heard either way is fine but this just the way i learned)-->
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you The comments really helped @TSR

Comment: Im just glad i could help, and welcome to stack overflow. If you could accept an answer that would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

The updated javascript, I hope this works because I have not tested it:

```
function upDate(PreviewPic){
    var imageLarge = document.getElementById("image");
    imageLarge.innerHTML += '<img src="'+PreviewPic.src+'">';
    imageLarge.innerHTML += PreviewPic.alt;
}

function unDo(){
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
}
```

the upDate function will use the `(this)` value of the `onmouseover=""`, the this element will be the PreviewPic, this variable will be used to insert the src and alt into the `#image` element. I have not edited the unDo function, this will reset the innerHTML of the `#image` element.

Answer (score 0):

I used angular, witch is over kill; but it works and you could easily add more images. :)

```js
var app = angular.module("MainApp", []);

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.display = {};
    $scope.album = [{
        img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg",
        name: "Styling with a Bandana"
    }, {
        img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG",
        name: "With My Boy"
    }, {
        img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg",
        name: "Young Puppy"
    }];
    
    $scope.newDisplay = function(item) {
        $scope.display = item;
    }
    
}]);
```

```css
div.gallery {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MainApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">-->
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="display" ng-model="display">
        <img ng-src="{{ display.img }}" alt="">
        <h1>{{ display.name }}</h1></div>
    <div class="gallery" ng-repeat="item in album" ng-mouseover="newDisplay(item)">
        <img ng-src="{{ item.img }}" alt="">
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way tot make ti work without changing the HTML? @TSR

Comment: i'll give it a shot :); also are you going for vanila js?